# Pass array of connection strings in parameters file to bicep file to be used for loop for application service

Tags: arrays, json, azure, for-loop, azure-bicep

I am trying to create an application service to deploy via a CI/CD pipeline, however I am struggling create a `For` loop for the connection strings.

Im my parameters file I have the following:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        // Required Parameters
        ...
        // Optional Parameters
        "connectionStrings": [
            {
                "name": "Tracking",
                "connectionString": "...",
                "type": "SQLServer"
            }
            {
                "name": "Logs",
                "connectionString": "...",
                "type": "SQLServer"
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

I am passing this into the `main.bicep` file and the `appService.bicep` module file as a `param connectionStrings array`.

In the `appService.bicep` file I have the following for loop.

```
resource appServiceWeb 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: nameWeb
  location: location
  tags: tags
  kind: kind
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan_id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        ...
      ]
      connectionStrings: [for connectionString in connectionStrings: {
        name: connectionString.name
        connectionString: connectionString.connectionString
        type: connectionString.type
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
  "message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'properties.parameters.connectionStrings', line 1, position 280.'."
}
```

Comment: I have an alternative approach with `param` keyword. Community can help you providing the clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my issue. While my Json structure was legal, it wasn't the correct structure for bicep files.

I needed to add the `value` part below:

```json
"connectionStrings": {
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "TrackingEntities",
      "connectionString": "...",
      "type": "SQLServer"
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `connectionStrings` in `parameters.json` file, Include it with an array type in `main.bicep` file. If you pass in `parameters.json` it is expecting an object type and that is why for loop is throwing deserialized object error.

Usually to avoid this error, Pass `for` loop as

```bash
[for (connectionStrings, i) in connectionStrings: {
connectionStrings : <ResourceName>.properties.connectionStrings[i]
}
```

Alternatively, I would suggest you add in `main.bicep` file with `param` keyword as detailed above.

By referring to the sample [bicep template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/provision-resource-bicep), I made a few changes to your code and was able to deploy it successfully.

`main.bicep`:

```bash
param webAppName string = <AppNAme>
param sku string = '<SKU>'
param linuxFxVersion string = '' 
param location string = resourceGroup().location 
var appServicePlanName = <appServicePlanName>
var webSiteName = <webSiteName>
param connectionStrings array = [
            {
                name: 'Tracking'
                connectionString: ''
                type: 'SQLServer'
            }
            {
                name: 'Logs'
                connectionString: ''
                type: 'SQLServer'
            }
        ]
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: webSiteName
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
    connectionStrings: [for connectionString in connectionStrings: {
        name: connectionString.name
        connectionString: connectionString.connectionString
  }]
}
  }
}
```

*Build & deployment got succeeded:*

[image]

*Deployed a WebApp successfully:*

[image]

*Added connection Strings in* `WebApp -> Configuration`:

[image]

Comment: Hello Jahnavi: Quick question I see your type is SQL Server and what got created is MySQL. Can you please suggest what change is required in the main bicep for appservice resource to have the type also coming from the param declared?

Comment: I've already defined the connection string param array right. You can obtain it in the same way.

Comment: Got it will just add the 'type' param and get it from each value of array